# How do I evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^2 x^2y\cos(xy^2)\,dx\,dy$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

The question is $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^2 x^2y\cos(xy^2)\,dx\,dy$$

I have solved in this way but I am not getting the answer which is $\frac{-\pi}{16}$.  Is this process of mine correct ?Here is the image

[image]

Comment: When you integrate $\cos(xt)$ with respect to $t$, you should have a factor of $\frac{1}{x}$ in there.

Comment: @ConMan OP takes care of that. You can see the $x^2$ becomes an $x$

Comment: Ah, so it does, I mistook the crossing out for something else.

Comment: Where is your work beyond what you have shared? Do you know how to integrate $x \sin x$?

Comment: @Math Lover yes i know how to integrate xsinx but my answer is not coming to be (-pi)/16

Comment: I haven't checked but Dushyant already points out using Wolfram Alpha that $ - \pi/16$ is not the correct answer.

Comment: Please format using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264) whenever possible; avoid pictures when you can.

Answer (score 3):

Your work is correct, but the answer is not $-\frac{\pi}{16}$ as mentioned by Dushyant. Integrating by parts we have

$$\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}x\right)dx$$
$$=\left[-\frac{2x}{\pi^2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}x\right)\right]_{0}^{2}+\frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}x\right)dx$$
$$=-\frac{4}{\pi^2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi^2}{2}\right)+\frac{8}{\pi^4}\sin\left(\frac{\pi^2}{2}\right)$$